# How to create a small lookup table in R script

Tags: r

I want to make a small lookup table within an R script, but it seems difficult.

```
lookup <- data.frame(
  item=c("aaaa","bbbb","dddd"),
  price=c(1.00,2.50,3.65)
  )
lookup
```

The above works for really short lists, but already the item and price are getting out of alignment, and if we added a 20 char description it would be harder again. Is there an easy way to transpose it for something like

```
"Item", "Price", "Description" 
"aaaa", 1.00   , "A very nice set of aaas"
"bbbb", 2.00   , "More expensive bbbs"
...
"zzzz", 26.00  , "Zese are the most costly"
```

Comment: Keep it as CSV file, then read in, when needed? Also, have a look at knitr::kable package. e.g.: `kable(head(mtcars))`

Comment: Could you please specify your problem, are you sure "transpose" is what you want here? Does not seem like it.

Comment: You are using terms like "lookup" and "transpose" which do have specfic meanings when dealing with data problems in R. This is quite misleading. Furthermore, it is unclear what you are really after because you didn't supply context or explain the reasoning behind your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
lookup <- read.csv(text = '
"Item", "Price", "Description" 
"aaaa", 1.00   , "A very nice set of aaas"
"bbbb", 2.00   , "More expensive bbbs"
"zzzz", 26.00  , "Zese are the most costly"
')
```

It is better to keep it as *csv* file, then use `read.csv()` to read into R, and to have formatted output use `knitr::kable()` function:

```
library(knitr)

kable(lookup)

|Item | Price|Description              |
|:----|-----:|:------------------------|
|aaaa |     1|A very nice set of aaas  |
|bbbb |     2|More expensive bbbs      |
|zzzz |    26|Zese are the most costly |
```

Comment: Awesome - exactly what I wanted.  Just beware having any spaces after the last line.  If for example you have `...modst costly" ')code`  as the final line, that pesky space is treated as another line of input and you get an extra row.

Comment: Sorry - just getting the hang of the markdown and time for editing comments expired on me... final line was supposed to be `...most costly"   ')`.